# Best way to check if the indices of two arrays match

Tags: arrays, c, strcmp

I have a .txt file that is scanned into two arrays, called departures[236] and arrivals[236]. I have a function that is checking for the match of two user inputs, depart_input, and arrive_input, this is my code, however, this function keeps returning INVALID instead of the actual value of i.

```
int find_matching_indices(char *depart_input, char *arrival_input){
    for(int i = 0; i < MAX_ROUTES; i++){
        if (strcmp(depart_input, departure[i]) && strcmp(arrival_input, arrivals[i]))
            return i;
        else{
            continue;
        }
    }
    return INVALID;
}
```

Comment: You know, that `strcmp` returns `0` if the strings are same, do you? I would assume you want to use `!strcmp()` or `strcmp() ==0` in your condition.

Comment: It seems that the arrays `departure` and `arrivals` contain corresponding strings. Maybe you could create a struct holding a string for departure and another for arrival and make one array of that struct. If thinks belong together, put them together.

Comment: This may be a good candidate for [gperf](https://www.gnu.org/software/gperf/).

Answer (score 0):

strcmp return 0 when the two strings are identique.
Just add "!" before strcmp

```
if (!strcmp(depart_input, departure[i]) && !strcmp(arrival_input, arrivals[i]))
     return i;
```

and be aware that strcmp is case sensitive